# ¿Como hago para usar 2 variables de 8 bits en una de 16 bits?

Tags: c

Tengo dos variables (uint8 d1, d2) los cuales están de la siguiente manera d1(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1)MSB y d2(1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1)LSB, bien ahora quiero guardar estas dos variables de 8 bits en una de 16 bits (uint16 dTotal) esto para crear con esas dos variables de 8 bits una de 9 bits quedando dTotal de la siguiente manera:

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

(--------------)(---------------)

```
  MSB             LSB
```

Pero no se muy como realizar esto en lenguaje C puesto que no he trabajado mucho con esto y estoy en aprendizaje del lenguaje.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar una función como esta:

```
void combinar(uint8_t HI, uint8_t LO, uint16_t *resultado)
{
    *resultado = (HI << 8) | LO;
}
```

Conceptualmente hace lo siguiente:

1. Desplaza el valor `HI` ocho bits a la izquierda, así que partiendo del valor `0b11111111` pasamos al valor `0b1111111100000000`.
2. Lo combina con el operador *OR* binario con el valor `LO`, por lo que si este fuese `0b11111111` el resultado sería:

> ```
>    0b1111111100000000
> OR 0b0000000011111111
>    0b1111111111111111
> ```

El siguiente código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void combinar(uint8_t HI, uint8_t LO, uint16_t *resultado)
{
    *resultado = (HI << 8) | LO;
}

int main()
{
    uint8_t ca = 0xCA;
    uint8_t fe = 0xFE;
    uint16_t v;

    combinar(ca, fe, &v);

    printf("%x\n", v);

    return 0;
}
```

Muestra `cafe`<kbd>[como salida](https://tio.run/##VY7RCoJAFESfvV9xMYo1LOwlBC2IKBSCfiCIbdVa0DXWVYTq223VSnqbOczcuWzGUiquTTPigqVlFKNfqIjn89sa/pFQLYMq5xGyPLtwQSUpNXbPCoPQxq8@HHu9WGozlXFRpopGuQUPMAaLKyRBiL6ProVPXfLgBaBrmFEuSJf@XmRUp516u/EGlsQd2@8@rFurPADj9xyjto7ZOKmslt@ljiXEHNcnYdrYQxmrUgp09HrTvAE)</kbd>.